# update schema: doesn't work on a child entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

This is an entity that inherits a BaseUser:

```
namespace Dolphine\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $lastname;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="facebookId", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $facebookId;

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array($this->facebookId, parent::serialize()));
    }

    public function unserialize($data)
    {
        list($this->facebookId, $parentData) = unserialize($data);
        parent::unserialize($parentData);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $firstname
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
    }



    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $lastname
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Get the full name of the user (first + last name)
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFullName()
    {
        return $this->getFirstname() . ' ' . $this->getLastname();
    }

    /**
     * @param string $facebookId
     * @return void
     */
    public function setFacebookId($facebookId)
    {
        $this->facebookId = $facebookId;
        $this->setUsername($facebookId);
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFacebookId()
    {
        return $this->facebookId;
    }

    /**
     * @param Array
     */
    public function setFBData($fbdata)
    {
        if (isset($fbdata['id'])) {
            $this->setFacebookId($fbdata['id']);
            $this->addRole('ROLE_FACEBOOK');
        }
        if (isset($fbdata['first_name'])) {
            $this->setFirstname($fbdata['first_name']);
        }
        if (isset($fbdata['last_name'])) {
            $this->setLastname($fbdata['last_name']);
        }
        if (isset($fbdata['email'])) {
            $this->setEmail($fbdata['email']);
        }
    }

}
```

After running schema:update --force I get "no changes available for entities", yet my DB table "fos_user" doesn't contain the given fields above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I had configuration of the bundle set to yml instead of annotations.